# Getting origin name of request

Tags: scala, playframework

If I have a super simple controller function:

```
def pong = Action { implicit request =>
    request.remoteAddress // This is the IP address
    Ok("pong")
}
```

How can I get the origin's domain name?  I believe it is possible because by setting up a [CORS filter](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/CorsFilter) you can specify domain names to whitelist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
request.headers.get(ORIGIN).getOrElse("*")
```